# DOMDocument remove script tags from HTML source

Tags: php, html-parsing, xss, domdocument, script-tag

I used [@Alex's approach here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130867/remove-script-tag-from-html-content) to remove script tags from a HTML document using the built in DOMDocument. The problem is if I have a script tag with Javascript content and then another script tag that links to an external Javascript source file, not all script tags are removed from the HTML.

```
$result = '
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>
            hey
        </title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            alert("hello");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>hey</body>
</html>
';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
if($dom->loadHTML($result))
{
    $script_tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('script');

    $length = $script_tags->length;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        if(is_object($script_tags->item($i)->parentNode)) {
            $script_tags->item($i)->parentNode->removeChild($script_tags->item($i));
        }
    }

    echo $dom->saveHTML();
}
```

The above code outputs:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>hey</title>
        <script>
        alert("hello");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        hey
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see from the output, only the external script tag was removed. Is there anything I can do to ensure all script tags are removed?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your error is actually trivial. A `DOMNode` object (and all its descendants - `DOMElement`, `DOMNodeList` and a few others!) is automatically updated when its parent element changes, most notably when its number of children change. This is written on a couple of lines in the PHP doc, but is mostly swept under the carpet.

If you loop using `($k instanceof DOMNode)->length`, and subsequently remove elements from the nodes, you'll notice that the `length` property actually changes! I had to write my own library to counteract this and a few other quirks.

The solution:

```
if($dom->loadHTML($result))
{
    while (($r = $dom->getElementsByTagName("script")) && $r->length) {
            $r->item(0)->parentNode->removeChild($r->item(0));
    }
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

I'm not actually looping - just popping the first element one at a time. The result: http://sebrenauld.co.uk/domremovescript.php

Comment: Another solution is to just loop over the elements in reverse order.

Comment: Note that this breaks DOMDocument parsing when using loadHTML() because of the HTML markup in a Javascript string:

```<div>
 <script>
 var str = '</div>this does NOT get removed';
 </script>
</div>```

Answer (score 17):

To avoid that you get the surprises of a *live* node list -- that gets shorter as you delete nodes -- you could work with a copy into an array using `iterator_to_array`:

```
foreach(iterator_to_array($dom->getElementsByTagName($tag)) as $node) {
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
};
```