# PHP DOMDocument - ignore unexpected closing tags

Tags: php, html, wordpress, tags, domdocument

I'm kind of hacking my WordPress theme footer, and I found a little problem.

What I am doing is taking the footer of the parent theme, capturing the output, and using DOMDocument to modify an element. Here is my code:

```php
<?php
// I apologize in advance for my messy code....

/**
* JavaScript-like HTML DOM Element
*
* This class extends PHP's DOMElement to allow
* users to get and set the innerHTML property of lalalalala....
*
* @author Keyvan Minoukadeh - http://www.keyvan.net - keyvan@keyvan.net
* @see http://fivefilters.org (the project this was written for)
*/
// blahblahblah

ob_start();
require get_theme_root() . '/responsive/footer.php';
$output = ob_get_clean();

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->registerNodeClass('DOMElement', 'JSLikeHTMLElement');
$dom->loadHTML($output);
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
$classname="powered";
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]");
$elem = $nodes->item(0);

$elem->innerHTML = "hahaha..gotcha!";

echo $dom->saveHTML();
?>
```

However, the footer output contains two `</div>`s (unexpected closing tags) and that is making DOMDocument complain. In fact, it just gets rid of those `</div>`s and makes the page look weird. I can't just add `</div></div>` to the beginning of the output because there is stuffing around the `</div>`s.

Is there a way to get DOMDocument to ignore those unexpected tags and leave them there or should I use a different library?

Comment: no wordpress expert but this looks like the wrong approach towards theme modification.

Comment: @Dagon Absolutely. See [*Child Themes*](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

Comment: @Phil This is a child theme. I want to keep the stuff in the footer, but not cause issues when upgrading. I don't want ANY trace of the Powered by Wordpress footer, as my site is under brute force attack right now. Also, I want the powered by wordpress to say something else, like a link to a privacy policy.

Comment: For reference, those people looking for sites to attack...typically don't care about some text in the footer.  I'd be semi surprised if they even visited your site in a web browser.  They go by the presence of certain files available via certain URLs.

Comment: Just copy the theme's footer file into the child theme and modify it.  This DOMDocument crap is not worth the trouble; in fact, it's even *more* likely to break during upgrades, since you now depend on the document structure even more than if you'd just spit out some malformed HTML from a modified footer.

Comment: For anyone, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37758278/4949411) resolved the issue for me and DOMDocument is no longer removing closing tags inside `<script>` elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution!

Instead of using PHP's DOMDocument, I used the Simple HTML DOM library. That doesn't complain about the errors, and even reduces the amount of code!

```
<?php
// Simple HTML DOM Parser
require (get_stylesheet_directory() . '/core/includes/simple_html_dom.php');

ob_start();
require (get_theme_root() . '/responsive/footer.php');
$outputhtml = str_get_html(ob_get_clean());

$outputhtml->find("div.powered", 0)->innertext = "<a href='/privacy-policy'>Privacy</a>";

echo $outputhtml;
?>
```

Comment: Eh.   If it works for you, congrats.  My personal experience with simple_html_dom is that it is a steaming pile.  I personally had to remove it from a site and replace it with DOMDocument, because it was causing massive memory leaks.  Tried to download the latest version to test and see if the bug was fixed, and 2/3 of the test scripts either fail or outright die.

Comment: @cHao: simple_html_dom don't have automatic managed memory. You need to manage it your self.

Comment: @SoroushFalahati: *PHP* has automated memory management.  5.3 even includes a proper garbage collector.  But simple_html_dom somehow managed to fritter it all away.

Comment: @cHao, I didnt tested simple_html_dom in any other version of PHP except 2.2 and not sure if it makes any difference, yet I think simple_html_dom dont use PHP memory management system very well. AFAIK it keeps lot of data in memory unlike DOMDocument and don't release them automatically, so you need to take care of everything when you work with it.

Comment: @SoroushFalahati: Kinda makes the name a lie, doesn't it.  :P

Comment: @cHao, Currently yes. But in old days it was easier than parsing HTML any way. :D yet I think it is still very good for doing small things. Actually I don't like DOMDocument either :D Dom parsing is crap any way.