# PHP strip_tags but also contents of unordered list

Tags: php

I am using PHP's strip_tags as part of a process to show 'teaser' text for a web page, however this teaser text makes no sense when the stripped content included an unordered list. These lists are not wanted in the teaser so is there a way to remove everything in the ul and li html tags?

Comment: Add some code so we can see what you're working with.

Comment: Code such as the html variable given by Karl below is near enough, just that there is sometimes a class applied to the ul tag. I'm running this  as an addon in Statamic but that shouldn't confuse things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution with the use of DOMdocument.

```
$html = <<<EOF
<div id="test">
    <p>Foobar</p>
    <ul>
        <li>Foo</li>
        <li>Bar</li>
    </ul>
    <ol>
        <li>Bar</li>
        <li>Foo</li>
    </ol>
</div>
EOF;
$dom = new DOMDocument;
if($dom->loadHTML($html)) {
    foreach(array('ul','ol') as $listElement) {
        while (($r = $dom->getElementsByTagName($listElement)) && $r->length) {
                $r->item(0)->parentNode->removeChild($r->item(0));
        }
    }
}
$html = $dom->saveHTML();
echo trim(strip_tags($html));
```

And I used the code from this answer by Sébastien Renauld.
[DOMDocument remove script tags from HTML source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925961/domdocument-remove-script-tags-from-html-source)

Comment: Thanks. This works well for simple lists (I stripped the EOF stuff). Some of my lists have a class applied in the ul tag and this seems to stop it working. <ul class="myclass"> Is there a way to tweak it so it will work in this case too? That's as complex as it should get for my case.

Comment: It seems to work for me with classes on the list-elemnts. Could you post your HTML and PHP script on pastebin or another site?

Comment: My mistake. It appears to be an anchor tag outside the list it doesn't like. The offending text is generated by ckeditor as: <a id="goal" name="goal">Our goal</a>. If I make the id and name different to test it's ok but otherwise it all falls over. This has become a different issue but thanks for the solution to the first!