# remove multiple line using str_replace

Tags: php, str-replace, multiline

I want to remove this multi line with str_replace

```
<div><i>Hello</i><br/>
<!-- Begin: Hello.text -->
<script src="http://site.com/hello.php?id=12345" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<!-- End: Hello.text --></div>
```

12345 = random number

Comment: You want to remove the entire div?

Comment: Use a method from above link to remove that node.

Comment: Removed response, hoping OP can clarify this question.

Comment: actually the problem is like this, i want to parse a page using simplehtmldom, and on that page contain that script (show up few times randomly inside the text) so i want to remove it, and to make it simple i want to use str_replace, but the problem the id is random and its multi line, i dont know how to make it work..

Comment: if the ID is random you need to use `preg_replace()`

Comment: preg_replace / str_replace fine for me as long that code is gone :) (sorry still newbie here)

Comment: cryptic, can u help me give sample code for my problem sir, bit confuse with explanation on that page

Comment: this site is bad for asking for getting code written for you especially when a question is not precise. you normally can improve this by providing a code-example as context. And also keep in mind that only you ask yourself how something is written in code does not qualify a programming question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$pattern = <<< EOD
@<div><i>Hello</i><br/>
<!-- Begin: Hello\.text -->
<script src="http://site\.com/hello\.php\?id=\d++" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<!-- End: Hello\.text --></div>
?@
EOD;

echo preg_replace($pattern,'',$text);
```

Comment: Result on Ideone: http://ideone.com/yYPGhO

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$html = '<div><i>Hello</i><br/><!-- Begin: Hello.text --><script src="http://site.com/hello.php?id=12345" type="text/javascript"></script><!-- End: Hello.text --></div>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();

// load the HTML string we want to strip
$doc->loadHTML($html);

// get all the script tags
$script_tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('script');

$length = $script_tags->length;

// for each tag, remove it from the DOM
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
  $script_tags->item($i)->parentNode->removeChild($script_tags->item($i));
}

// get the HTML string back
$no_script = $doc->saveHTML();


echo $no_script;

// this removes every script tag from your input ($html)
```

Taken from **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7131085/1150613)**

Example in action **[here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/RpqHxA)**

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: The 12345 = random number part... It seems that he wants to strip that portion? Will remove if that's not the case... Pretty poorly worded question

Comment: The question mentions removing multiple lines, it is poorly worded though.

Comment: No, he wants to strip the entire thing, he is just saying the number can be different each time.