# strip_tags, remove javascript

Tags: php, strip-tags

I have this problem with the code i'm running right now.

My code is that I enter an URL and when i click submit it removes all tags. I use `strip_tags` for that one. And then I use `preg_match_all("/((?:\w'|\w|-)+)/", $contents, $words);` which creates and array of every word. I then have a foreach loop which will count all words and then place it in a table with another foreach loop.

The problem is for example. Say I enter an URL which has the following content:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>titel1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="div1">
            <h1 class="class2">
                Testpage-h1
            </h1>
            <p>
                Testpage-p
            </p>
        </div>
        <script>
            alert('hallo');
            document.getElementById('class2');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This will echo out the following using my code:

```
document         1
getElementById1  1
class2'          1
hallo            1
alert            1
Testpage-h1      1
Testpage-p       1
titel1           1
```

(sorry for placing this as 'code' but it wouldn't let me use breaks otherwise, or place the numbers under eachother)

My problem with this is that it shouldn't show what is between the `<script></script>` tags, because that has no use for me anyway. Is there a solution for this matter?

I've tried such things as sanitize filterering but this didn't help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove < script >...< /script > from your string before any calculations:

```
$text = preg_replace('#<script(.*?)>(.*?)</script>#is', '', $text);
```

Or another solutions (slower, but sometimes more correct) from [remove script tag from HTML content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130867/remove-script-tag-from-html-content):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();

// load the HTML string we want to strip
$doc->loadHTML($html);

// get all the script tags
$script_tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('script');

$length = $script_tags->length;

// for each tag, remove it from the DOM
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
  $script_tags->item($i)->parentNode->removeChild($script_tags->item($i));
}

// get the HTML string back
$no_script_html_string = $doc->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem! If I may ask, what could go wrong using the `preg_replace` over your other solution?

Comment: It is possible to have a problems with not completely valid html code (for example, if you have < script > block inside another < script > block or something like this).