# Regex replace text outside script tag

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace

I have this HTML:

```
"This is simple html text <script language="javascript">simple simple text text</script> text"
```

I need to match only words that are outside script tag. I mean if I want to match “simple” and “text” I should get the results only from “This is simple html text” and the last part “text” — the result will be “simple” 1 match, “text” 2 matches. Could anyone help me with this? I’m using PHP.

I found a similar answer for match text outside a tag:

```
(text|simple)(?![^<]*>|[^<>]*</)
```

[Regex replace text outside html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621568/regex-replace-text-outside-html-tags)

But couln't put to work for a specific tag (script):

```
(text|simple)(?!(^<script*>)|[^<>]*</)
```

ps: This question is not a duplicate ([strip_tags, remove javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22781853/strip-tags-remove-javascript)). 'Cause i´m not trying to strip tags, or select the content inside the script tag. i´m trying replace content outside the tag "script".

Comment: Do you absolutely need matching, or capturing groups will do?

Comment: When you want to parse html with confidence, use an html parser not regex.  SO says this over and over and over.  IIRC there is even a note that the SO software pops up that says "don't use regex to parse html".

Comment: @mickmackusa, but when you use a parser they stop working parsing a malformed html.

I think this question is not a duplicate. 'Cause i´m not trying to strip tags, i´m trying replace content outside the tag "script".

Comment: Retracted dupe link, it is merely related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My pattern will use `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` to disqualify matched script tags and their contents.

`text` and `simple` will be match on every qualifying occurrence.

Regex Pattern: `~<script.*?/script>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|text|simple~`

[Pattern / Replacement Demo Link](https://regex101.com/r/pefZM4/3)

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e3131e5bbc078f71b9a5d7d576b6ae49ca73bbc5))

```
$strings=['This has no replacements',
    'This simple text has no script tag',
    'This simple text ends with a script tag <script language="javascript">simple simple text text</script>',
    'This is simple html text is split by a script tag <script language="javascript">simple simple text text</script> text',
    '<script language="javascript">simple simple text text</script> this text starts with a script tag'
];

$strings=preg_replace('~<script.*?/script>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|text|simple~','***replaced***',$strings);

var_export($strings);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'This has no replacements',
  1 => 'This ***replaced*** ***replaced*** has no script tag',
  2 => 'This ***replaced*** ***replaced*** ends with a script tag <script language="javascript">simple simple text text</script>',
  3 => 'This is ***replaced*** html ***replaced*** is split by a script tag <script language="javascript">simple simple text text</script> ***replaced***',
  4 => '<script language="javascript">simple simple text text</script> this ***replaced*** starts with a script tag',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's assured that `script` will be present then simply match with

```
(.*?)<script.*</script>(.*)
```

The text outside the tag will appear in submatch 1 and 2. If `script` is optional then do `(.*?)(<script.*</script>)?(.*)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution

```
([\w\s]*)(?:<script.*?\/script>)(.*)$
```

and here is the demo on https://regex101.com/r/1Lthi8/1

Comment: I´m trying to replace string outside the <script></script> tag.

Comment: yes, this is captured in group 1 as regex101 highlighted `This is simple html text `

Comment: Match 2 is inside the tag and the last word "text" is not being selected.
and finally, this is trying to ignore all tags, not the specifc tag "script".

Comment: ha .. I see the problem ... I missed seeing that second text. I updated my answer and the regex demo. Let me know if you still have issues/questions

Answer (score 0):

***Just an fyi, as far as tags go, it is impossible to ignore a single tag

without parsing all tags.***

You can *SKIP/FAIL* past html tags and invisible content.
This will find the words you're looking for.

`'~<(?:(?:(?:(script|style|object|embed|applet|noframes|noscript|noembed)(?:\s+(?>"[\S\s]*?"|\'[\S\s]*?\'|(?:(?!/>)[^>])?)+)?\s*>)[\S\s]*?</\1\s*(?=>))|(?:/?[\w:]+\s*/?)|(?:[\w:]+\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|\'[\S\s]*?\'|[^>]?)+\s*/?)|\?[\S\s]*?\?|(?:!(?:(?:DOCTYPE[\S\s]*?)|(?:\[CDATA\[[\S\s]*?\]\])|(?:--[\S\s]*?--)|(?:ATTLIST[\S\s]*?)|(?:ENTITY[\S\s]*?)|(?:ELEMENT[\S\s]*?))))>(*SKIP)(?!)|(?:text|simple)~'`

https://regex101.com/r/7ZGlvW/1

Formated

```
    <
    (?:
         (?:
              (?:
                                                 # Invisible content; end tag req'd
                   (                             # (1 start)
                        script
                     |  style
                     |  object
                     |  embed
                     |  applet
                     |  noframes
                     |  noscript
                     |  noembed 
                   )                             # (1 end)
                   (?:
                        \s+ 
                        (?>
                             " [\S\s]*? "
                          |  ' [\S\s]*? '
                          |  (?:
                                  (?! /> )
                                  [^>] 
                             )?
                        )+
                   )?
                   \s* >
              )

              [\S\s]*? </ \1 \s* 
              (?= > )
         )

      |  (?: /? [\w:]+ \s* /? )
      |  (?:
              [\w:]+ 
              \s+ 
              (?:
                   " [\S\s]*? " 
                |  ' [\S\s]*? ' 
                |  [^>]? 
              )+
              \s* /?
         )
      |  \? [\S\s]*? \?
      |  (?:
              !
              (?:
                   (?: DOCTYPE [\S\s]*? )
                |  (?: \[CDATA\[ [\S\s]*? \]\] )
                |  (?: -- [\S\s]*? -- )
                |  (?: ATTLIST [\S\s]*? )
                |  (?: ENTITY [\S\s]*? )
                |  (?: ELEMENT [\S\s]*? )
              )
         )
    )
    >
    (*SKIP)
    (?!)
 |  
    (?: text | simple )
```

---

Or, a much faster approach is to match both tags *AND* the text you're
looking for.

Matching the tags moves past them.

If you're doing a replace, use a callback to determine what to replace.
Group 1 is a *TAG* or an *Invisible Content run*.
Group 3 is the words you're looking to replace.

So, in the callback, if group 1 matched, just return group 1.
If group 3 matched, replace with what you want to replace it with.

The regex

`'~(<(?:(?:(?:(script|style|object|embed|applet|noframes|noscript|noembed)(?:\s+(?>"[\S\s]*?"|\'[\S\s]*?\'|(?:(?!/>)[^>])?)+)?\s*>)[\S\s]*?</\2\s*(?=>))|(?:/?[\w:]+\s*/?)|(?:[\w:]+\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|\'[\S\s]*?\'|[^>]?)+\s*/?)|\?[\S\s]*?\?|(?:!(?:(?:DOCTYPE[\S\s]*?)|(?:\[CDATA\[[\S\s]*?\]\])|(?:--[\S\s]*?--)|(?:ATTLIST[\S\s]*?)|(?:ENTITY[\S\s]*?)|(?:ELEMENT[\S\s]*?))))>)|(text|simple)~'`

https://regex101.com/r/7ZGlvW/2

---

This regex is comparable to how SAX and DOM parsers parse tags.
I've posted this hundreds of times on SO.

Here is an example of how to remove all html tags:

https://regex101.com/r/oCVkZv/1

Comment: This regEx works fine, but use a lot of memory, causing the error:

Firefox: The connection was reset
Chrome: (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset.
IE: Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage

Comment: @PauloACosta - I see you've accepted a _skip/fail_ answer as I originally posted. But, as I said `it is impossible to ignore a single tag
 without parsing all tags`. And using skip/fail with my regex _will_ be slower. Where you get that _MEMORY_ problem is _not_ from the regex. Otherwise, for speed, I said _not_ to use skip/fail and instead just match both tags and text you need using my later regex. You made the wrong choice in an answer. That's too bad...