# Laravel5 - How to render only html tags not javascript in Blade?

Tags: security, laravel, laravel-5, xss

I want to render user input $content as HTML but prevent JavaScript to be executed (for preventing XSS attacks) ın blade template engine. Following code renders both HTML and JavaScript.

```
{!! $content !!}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: AFAIK, that's not built into Blade. You need to use `strip_tags` to pull out `<script>` and something like `DOMDocument` to parse out `onload`, etc.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7131156/351330).

Comment: you need to build your own function to do this.

Comment: `strip_tags` shouldn't be relied upon. He needs something like HTMLpurifier. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing built into Blade to do this. It gives you the `{!!  !!}` option so you can do your own cleaning when necessary. If you want your HTML to work, but prevent Javascript, then you will need to do some work to specially purify it. Here's a package that implements the popular [HTMLpurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) in Laravel 5:

https://github.com/etcinit/purifier

You can see that by its default configuration it uses a whitelist to ensure javascript doesn't pass through:

*src/Chromabits/Purifier/Purifier.php*

```
protected function getDefaultConfig()
{
        return [
            'HTML.Doctype' => 'XHTML 1.0 Strict',
            'HTML.Allowed' => 'div,b,strong,i,em,a[href|title],ul,ol,li'
                . ',p[style],br,span[style],img[width|height|alt|src]',
            'CSS.AllowedProperties' => 'font,font-size,font-weight,font-style'
                . ',font-family,text-decoration,padding-left,color'
                . ',background-color,text-align',
            'AutoFormat.AutoParagraph' => true,
            'AutoFormat.RemoveEmpty' => true,
        ];
}
```

Use it in your controller like:

```
public function getIndex(Request $request)
{
    return $this->purifier->clean($request->input('first_name'));
}
```

The other alternative would be to not allow your users to input direct HTML but perhaps instead use something like [Markdown](https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Markdown). This is what StackOverFlow [does](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: It looks like to be work. But I think there must be something easier.

Comment: Updated my answer a bit more to give you more insight.

Comment: Thank you very much prograhammer

Comment: Have you considered using Markdown instead (like Stackoverflow does)? https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Markdown