# How to get body content without javascript code

Tags: php

To get content in the body tag, I'm using the code below.

```
$html = @file_get_contents($url);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body');
$body = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

How to remove js codes from the $body? Any js code that will look like

`<script>
/*Some js code*/
</script>`

Comment: Already asked:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130867/remove-script-tag-from-html-content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130867/remove-script-tag-from-html-content) has fixed my issue. The code below completely removes script tags and their content from the body tag:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    @$doc->loadHTML($html);
    $script = $doc->getElementsByTagName('script');

    $remove = [];
    foreach ($script as $item) {
        $remove[] = $item;
    }

    foreach ($remove as $item) {
        $item->parentNode->removeChild($item);
    }

    $node = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body');
    $body = $node->item(0)->nodeValue;

    echo $body;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$html = preg_replace("/<script.*?\/script>/s", "", $html);
```

When doing regex things might go wrong, so it's safer to do like this:

```
$html = preg_replace("/<script.*?\/script>/s", "", $html) ? : $html;
```

So that when the "accident" happen, we get the original `$html` instead of empty string.

Comment: This removes only the script tags, but leave the javascript content. The idea is to remove both the script tags and the javascript content.

Answer (score 1):

If you already using `DOMDocument` then why won't you remove nodes with that?!

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
@$dom->loadHTMLFile("from_link_to.html");
$scripts = $dom->getElementsByTagName('script');
foreach ($scripts as $script) {
    $scripts->removeChild($script);
}
...
```

Take closer look to [The DOMDocument class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and by the way `regular expression` is **nightmare** for such tasks.