# how to escape only <script> tag using htmlspecialchars() in php

Tags: php

I have a string , in my  sql database that has come from user.

```
$str ='<h2 contenteditable="true">I am a not a good user <script>alert("hacked") </script> </h2>';
```

if I echo it as it is then it is not good So I use htmlspecialchars(); to escape the special html chracters

```
echo htmlspecialchars($str);
```

This will save me from hacking , but i want to keep other tags (like <h2> ) as it is , i don't want it to change , is their a way if i could only escape specific tag using htmlspecialchars();

Comment: function addslashes ?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I think `strip_tags()` is what you are looking for. You can add allowed tags to the second parameter</strike>

<strike>Check out this function from the PHP Docs</strike>

```
$strippedinput = strip_tags_attributes($nonverifiedinput,"<p><br><h1><h2><h3><a><img>","class,style");

function strip_tags_attributes($string,$allowtags=NULL,$allowattributes=NULL){
    $string = strip_tags($string,$allowtags);
    if (!is_null($allowattributes)) {
        if(!is_array($allowattributes)) $allowattributes = explode(",",$allowattributes);
        if(is_array($allowattributes)) $allowattributes = implode(")(?<!",$allowattributes);
        if (strlen($allowattributes) > 0) $allowattributes = "(?<!".$allowattributes.")";
        $string = preg_replace_callback("/<[^>]*>/i",create_function( '$matches', 'return preg_replace("/ [^ =]*'.$allowattributes.'=(\"[^\"]*\"|\'[^\']*\')/i", "", $matches[0]);' ),$string);
    }
return $string;
}
```

As Gerrit0 pointed out, you shouldn't use regex to parse HTML

Comment: is it secure enough ?

Comment: This will only allow tags you specify, so basically yes. This won't prevent you from SQL injection or so, but only remove the HTML-tags you don't allow

Comment: Are u sure? because I am creating a international website , If it gets hacked ,  I will blame u.  lol

Comment: This is a **very bad idea**. `strip_tags('<p onmouseover="alert(\'xxs\');">Oops!</p>', '<p>');`

Comment: rpi would u please add link for this function @rpi

Comment: @rpi, still a bad idea. Assuming the OP wants to allow `<a>` tags with the `href` attribute (not an unreasonable assumption I believe) this function will still break with `<a href="javascript:alert('xxs');">Alert</a>`.

Comment: @Gerrit0 but could javascript can be used in <img src attribute ?

Comment: I think this is good solution if u are not using , attribute , like href,onmouse,onclick, (Where javascript can be added) .,So this solution is very good, what do u think @Gerrit0

Comment: On very old browsers (IE 6) Javascript in src attributes would be executed. Newer browsers are no longer vulnerable to the attack.

Comment: I still don't believe this answer is a good idea to use. For one thing, `create_function` uses `eval()`... seems like a bad idea. An anonymous function should be used instead. Additionally, while the regex appears to work with some very basic tests that I ran, there is no guarantee that it is foolproof. I would strongly advise using something like [htmlpurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) instead.

Comment: And I broke it. The function will allow the following html (even if `onclick` is not an allowed attribute) `<p onclick=javascript:alert('xxs')>Test</p>`.

Comment: @Gerrit0 In that case, I'll withdraw the answer

Answer (score 0):

I was about to propose something very basic with regular expressions but I found this here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7131156/6219628

After reading more of the docs, I didn't found anything to ignore specific tags with just htmlspecialchars(), which doesn't sound surprising.

EDIT: And since using regex to parse html seems to be evil, you may eventually appreciate reading this bulky answer :)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/6219628

Answer (score 0):

Note that just removing the `<script>` tag isn't sufficient; there are many other ways that users can inject malicious content into your site.

If you want to restrict the HTML tags that users can input, use a tool like [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) which uses a whitelist of allowable tags and attributes.