# php remove script tags from full $content body and or head, inline, by index etc

Tags: javascript, php, regex, explode, head

This topic would not let me request it's solutions for the body, and or head,
inline, by index etc.

[remove script tag from HTML content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130867/remove-script-tag-from-html-content/46507040#46507040)

I want control over which and how much script I remove.

I'm hoping I don't have to go through the arguments about using certain 
things other than regex all over again. The answer I liked the most on this topic was from Binh as thusly:

```
$html = preg_replace("/<script.*?\/script>/s", "", $html) ? : $html;
```

I want this approach with as much granularity control as possible however, this removes script from the entire `$content`. I want to see this for just removing script from the body, (or from body on down to far bottom).

And also just removing script from the head, (or body on up to far top). Also by index. like 1st in body, 4th in head, etc.

Finally, I'd like to see inline element js stuff removal, with as much control
as possible.

Thanks

Comment: "The answer I liked the most on this topic was from Binh" — Shame it doesn't work. https://pastebin.com/t28dn6Zt

Answer (score 1):

I will eventually answer your question, let me get this explanation of what you're about to do over though

As you have not stated, I'm not quite sure why you would want to do this. Gathering raw html from a user and then displaying it elsewhere is considered a huge security hole. To get rid of all javascript would be difficult using purely a regex. Ridding the script tags would be easy, but removing the inline javascript would be the difficult part. While possible, I am going to advise finding another way to perform your task other than giving the user a javascript-stripped version of the webpage.

One way you could do it is via an iframe. Using

```
<iframe src="html_you_want_to_strip" sandbox=""></iframe>
```

will disable all javascript from running inside the iframe. Bear in mind that there are still other ways malicious items can be loaded into your website without the use of javascript.

Now that I've explained what you SHOULD do when it comes to stripping javascript, to answer your question,

A. Deleting script tags from just the body or just the header:

The best way to get granularity when removing javascript would be to use PHP's DOMDocument class. Basically, you will load the document up into this DOMDocument class and strip it of whatever script tags you want. For example, if you just wanted to get rid of the script tags in the body, you could write something like this:

```
<?php
$html = "the HTML you want filtered";
$DOM = new DOMDocument('1.0','utf-8');
$DOM->loadHTML($html);
$bodyTags = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('body');
/* 
 We will run under the assumption that the user has the ability to add two 
 body tags and hide information in the second one, that is why we don't 
 just use $DOM->getElementsByTagName('body')[0] 
*/
foreach($bodyTags as $body){
    foreach($body->getElementsByTagName('script') as $script){
        $script->parentNode->removeChild($script);
        /*
         The reason we have to this is because you cant just do 
         $script->remove(), that would be too easy :)
        */
    }
}
```

The same code above could be used to strip scripts from the head tag. If you wanted to delete items with a certain index, you could do the following with your foreach

```
$i=0;
foreach($body->getElementsByTagName('script') as $script){
    if($i!==(INDEX_TO_KEEP)){
        $script->parentNode->removeChild($script);
    }
}
```

B. Removing the inline javascript

We can use the same DOMDocument parser, except parsing over all elements this time looking for all javascript events (which thankfully all start with on). The code will look as follows.

```
<?php
//starting where the last code leaves off
foreach($DOM->getElementsByTagName('*') as $element){
    //This selects all elements
    foreach($element->attributes as $attribute){
        if(preg_match('/on.*/',$attribute)==1){
            /*
             "on" looks for on and ".*" states that there 
             can be anything after the on (onmousemove,onload,etc.)
            */
            $element->removeAttribute($attribute)
        }
    }
}
```

At the end of your code you will want to save the stripped HTML and return it back to the user

```
$parsedHTML = $DOM->saveHTML()
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. It's going to take me a few days to absorb and test your wonderful lesson. You are very enlightened. I wish I could PM you. I was starting work on "explode" for this. The last post (linked) seemed not 100% pro about the built-in DomDocument thing. I have seen other built-ins come up short. I will have to rethink a lot of things thanks to you. So are you saying that all Ajax, Proxy, CORS, etc. where user provides the URL, have no hope of being secure? Whitelists? iframes? Thanks

Comment: Any time you allow the user to run Javascript on your webpage you run a huge security risk. Iframes are able to segregate the users code from the overarching website’s but they aren’t perfect. For example, because the user created the html, it must be hosted on your site. This means that the Javascript functions created by your users have access to all authentication cookies, that’s something you never want to happen. If you could elaborate on what your overall project is, I might be able to help find a solution that does not require the user to create their own Javascript.