# DOMDocument::loadHTML() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given when trying to use LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED parameter

Tags: php, domdocument

Currently, when I use the DOMDocument object and call saveHTML() it automatically adds some html tags I do not want. I tried the solution suggested here(https://stackoverflow.com/a/31426408/3659230) and when I do I get this error:

*DOMDocument::loadHTML() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given*

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED|LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
```

Seems pretty simple but I can't seem to get it to work. I am using PHP version 5.5.3

Answer (score 2):

The `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED` and `LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD` are only defined from PHP 5.4 upwards.

If a constant is not defined, PHP (idiotically) treats it as a string. So on PHP 5.3 and below, your code is actually

```
$doc->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'), 'LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED'|'LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD');
```

or, once the bitwise operator has been executed:

```
$doc->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'), 'LIBXML_HTML_NOMMVL]ED');
```

Which is obviously not what you intend! Your best option, if possible, is to upgrade to a newer version of PHP.

Comment: I am using PHP version 5.5.3 so it doesn't seem like it's a version problem.

Comment: @dpst Can you check the version of libxml then? `var_dump(LIBXML_DOTTED_VERSION);`

Comment: the libxml version is 2.7.6

Comment: the version seems to be the problem. LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED isn't supported until version 2.7.7 (http://php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php#constant.libxml-html-noimplied)